# Text of label in UI file can't be changed

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyside2

I tried it.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore
from PySide2.QtUiTools import QUiLoader
from maya.app.general.mayaMixin import MayaQWidgetBaseMixin
import shiboken2 as shiboken
import os

UIFILEPATH = 'D:/MAYA/pyside_pick/ui/PicsTest5.ui'

class MainWindow(MayaQWidgetBaseMixin,QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(MainWindow,self).__init__(parent)
        
        self.UI = QUiLoader().load(UIFILEPATH)
        
        self.setWindowTitle(self.UI.windowTitle())
        
        self.setCentralWidget(self.UI)
        #image
        img = QtGui.QPixmap('D:/MAYA/pyside_pick/images/imgKohaku.png')
        self.scene = QtWidgets.QGraphicsScene(self)
        item = QtWidgets.QGraphicsPixmapItem(img)
        self.scene.addItem(item)
        self.UI.graphicsView_char_1.setScene(self.scene)

        #filter
        self._filter = Filter()
        self.installEventFilter(self._filter)
        
        self.UI.pSphere1.installEventFilter(self._filter)
        
        
        #primary
        self.UI.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : white;}")
        self.UI.label.setText("A")
        
    def labelTest(self):
        
        self.UI.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : red;}")
        self.UI.label.setText("B")
        print('D')
        
        return False
     
    
    
class Filter(QtCore.QObject):
    
    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        win = MainWindow()
        
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print(widget.objectName())
            cmds.select(widget.objectName())
            win.labelTest()
        return False
        
    
def main():
    
    win = MainWindow()
    win.show()
    
        
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I clicked the button that 'pSphere1', but
`self.UI.label.setStyleSheet("QLabel {color : red;}") self.UI.label.setText("B")`
were look like it's not working.
I can change it inside define with UI loaded, but can't I do setText from outside?

How can I change the label of an imported UI file?
I find this, but I really do not understand. I couldn't find any mention of them beyond this page.
[Change comboBox values in Qt .ui file with PySide2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63294764/change-combobox-values-in-qt-ui-file-with-pyside2)
If you know, I also want you to tell me where to put them.

Comment: Maybe we need to convert UI files to PY files?

Comment: Sorry but your code has too many syntax and indentation errors, so please [edit] your question and fix them. Read more about [formatting code](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362), and carefully check the code in the post preview before submitting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is within the `eventFilter()`, and specifically the first line:

```py
    win = MainWindow()
```

This will create a **new** main window instance, which clearly doesn't make sense, since you obviously want to interact with the *existing* one.

While you could add the instance as an argument in the filter constructor in order to get a reference to the instance and directly call the function, that wouldn't be very good from the OOP point of view, as objects should never directly access attributes of their "parents".

A better and more correct approach would be to use a custom signal instead, and connect it from the main window instance:

```py
class Filter(QtCore.QObject):
    testSignal = QtCore.Signal()

    def eventFilter(self, widget, event):
        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.MouseButtonPress:
            print(widget.objectName())
            cmds.select(widget.objectName())
            self.testSignal.emit()
        return False


class MainWindow(MayaQWidgetBaseMixin, QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # ...
        self._filter.testSignal.connect(self.labelTest)
```

Note that widgets could *accept* events and prevent propagation (for instance, buttons or graphics views that have selectable or movable items), so you might not receive the event in the filter in those cases.

Comment: Thank you, genius. You're crazy to get the words I need so quickly!